# How to get Windows Explorer back after multiple change of file manager?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry

A few months ago I shifted from Windows Explorer to Explorer++ and then Cubic Explorer. This messed up my registry, and I cant get Windows Explorer back now. It works if I run from Start Menu but not when I click desktop icons like My Computer, Recycle Bin, etc. If unregister Cubic explorer from registry and try to open any desktop icons I get Error as EXPLORER.EXE "Application not found".

How can I get Windows Explorer back?

Answer (score 2):

Run Microsoft System File Checker (`sfc /scannow`) in an administrative command prompt.

> System File Checker is a utility in Windows that allows users to scan
>   for corruptions in Windows system files and restore corrupted files. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833